# MySQL-PHP --> ID auto_increment no incrementa de a 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Mi aplicación web registra un usuario y lo guarda en la BD pero los id's van 4-9-18-27-48-57-66-75. 
Cómo haga para que el auto incremento sea de a 1? Por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Esta es la función que inserta el nuevo $usuario en la tabla:
*la funcion recibe $_POST como parámetro $usuario.

`function guardarUsuarioDB($usuario) {
  useDB();
  global $db;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (default,:name, :email, :password)";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindValue(":name", $usuario["name"]);
  $query->bindValue(":email", $usuario["email"]);
  $query->bindValue(":password", $usuario["password"]);
  $query->execute();
  $usuario["id"] = $db->lastInsertId();
  return $usuario;
}`

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué a tu función `guardarUsaurioDB` solo le pasas un parametro? y luego adentro le mandas los 3...

Comment: Porque cuando la implemento en la aplicacion, lo que le paso como parametro es `$_POST` que  es un array asociativo y tiene las posiciones ["name], ["email"], ["password"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En MySQL nada asegura que el id que se genere automáticamente se incremente de 1 en 1 a no ser que tu lo especifiques. Internamente Mysql utiliza secuencias para establecer los IDs. Esto quiere decir que si llegado el momento en la secuencia, por lo que sea existen valores anteriores que han quedado libres es posible que los reutilice en vez de generar un id nuevo.

Por eso uno de los principios en el diseño de bases de datos es que el campo que represente el identificador de una tupla de datos carezca completamente de significado, porque en caso de que no fuerces tu a que se lleve un control sobre el mismo, este valor no tiene por qué ser secuencial.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es asegurarte de que tu tabla la hayas creado cómo lo dice la documentación:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Y en segunda verifica si al insertarlo directo en la base de datos, si te incrementa normalmente, de lo contrario algo pudiera a llegar a estar mal en tu consulta preparada.